# Partial mocking in mockito - force method into exception and continue

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method with some logic and an exception block and would like to test the contents in the exception block.

Method:

```
Class Validator() {

    protected Validator(blah,blah) {

    }

    protected boolean doStuff(String a, String b) {

        try {
          isValidInput(a){
        } catch (Exception e) {
            b = "unknown error"
        }
    }
```

test case:

```
@Test
public void testException() {

Validator testValidator = new testValidator(blah, blah);

        Validator spy = spy(testValidator);
        String var2 = "unknown error"
        doReturn(new Exception()).when(spy.doStuff(var1, var2));

        assertEquals("unknown error", var2);
}
```

How can I force the real method to go into exception block and continue stubbing?

Comment: That wouldn't work anyway, because `var2` in your test won't reflect the value you set in the method you're testing.

Comment: what if I mock var2 to "unknown error"?

Comment: What's the method supposed to return if there's an exception? That's the only thing you need to test, because it's the only thing exposed by the method. Pass in input that generates an exception, or stub out `isValidInput` to guarantee a thrown exception. Subclassing can also do that.

Comment: if there is an exception, it returns false. In the exception block, I write some data to a string object which is passed as input arg to isValidInput(). If I stub out isValidInput, I won't be able to access the data written to the string object which is what I need. I also understand that I have provided limited info. here and providing a bigger picture would really help. Thanks for the comments, Dave

Comment: As long as you understand that you can't write to an input parameter string and see it outside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, forget about using `spy` - if `isValidInput` is able to throw an exception, then **make it throw an exception**.

If there is a collaborator used within `isValidInput()` that can throw an `Exception`, then mock *that* using Mockito. If it's just your code, then you should be able to set `a` such that it will generate an exception.

You still need to write a full set of tests on `isValidInput()` - investigate using the `expected` option in the @Test annotation (I assume you're using JUnit here) to specify that throwing an exception is the expected outcome of the test. But please don't throw `Exception` - using a meaningful subclass of it :-)

And as @Dave Newton commented, testing `var2` is *never* going to work outside the scope of `doStuff`.

Comment: agreed about testing var2. say, I mock the collaborator to throw an exception, will I be able to gather the contents of the string from my exception block. My collaborator is DefaultHttpClient.execute().

Comment: If I use expected anotation, the method doStuff() throws an exception but returns a boolean. So, if my unit test is expecting a certain type of exception, it gets swallowed.